# Is there a way thru Notion API to create a database entry based on a page template?

Tags: notion-api, notion

I am thinking of using Notion API to populate a database thousands of records based on an existing page template.

Please help…

I read Notion’s API documentation site but found no topic about using templates. I also searched the internet but could not find an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This might help: https://developers.notion.com/reference/block#template

Looks like templates are being deprecated for buttons.

Comment: I believe these are template buttons, not database templates. It seems like currently database templates are returned as "Pages" from a database. But you can't tell the different in the results so you need to name your templates accordingly